# How to check downloaded file exist in storage

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I stored PDF file in some path. If i downloaded the file, then click again download link how to give alert " you downloaded this file already. You want to redownload"?

```
function downloadFile(){

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(
        "dummy.html", {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("dummy.html","");
            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            fileEntry.remove();

            fileTransfer.download(
                "http://www.w3.org/2011/web-apps-ws/papers/Nitobi.pdf",
                sPath + "theFile.pdf",
                function(theFile) {
                    console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
                    showLink(theFile.toURI());
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                    console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
                }
            );
        }, fail);
    }, fail);
};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a very good question dude so i explain you in brief in this condition we have to check 2 condition fir

1. IS file with **filename is not present** on that filepath then we have to download the file
2. If **filename is present** on that file then **u have to check MD5** of that file because the other file with same name also may be present so in this condition we have to check file content with **file MD5**

   ```
   private File longF ;
   private MessageDigest md;
   longF = "your file path which u want to check weather it is present or not ";
   String digest ="";
   md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

           if(longF.exists())
                             {
                        digest = Constant.getDigest(new FileInputStream(longF), md, 2048);
                             }
                   else
                       {
                               System.out.println("not already exit according to file path condition " );

                             } 

                if(digest.equals(selectMD5))
           {
               System.out.println("Open That file=========");
                   }
   ```